# Creating method that accepts any value

Tags: go

While I am trying to learn Go (version 1.13) I was trying to implement basic network operation but I got tired with if err != nil and decided to be a bit smarter and created something like this

```
package operation

type Op struct {
    err error
    result interface{}
}

func Do(supplier func() (interface{}, error)) *Op {
    result, err := supplier()
    return &Op {result: result, err: err}
}

func (op *Op) onSuccessMap(supplier func(input interface{}) (interface{}, error)) *Op {
    if op.err != nil {
        return op
    } else {
        r, e := supplier(op.result)
        return &Op{result: r, err: e}
    }
}

func (op *Op) onFailure(errorHandler func(error) (interface{}, error)) *Op {
    if op.err == nil {
        return op
    } else {
        newResult, err := errorHandler(op.err)
        return &Op{result: newResult, err: err}
    }
}

func (op *Op) get() (interface{}, error) {
    return op.result, op.err
}
```

and I wanted to call it like

```
r,e := operation.Do(func()(*http.Request, error){
        return http.NewRequest("GET", "http://target.com", nil)
    })
    .onSuccessMap(func(req *http.Request)(*http.Response, error) {
        //... do something with request
    })
    .onSuccessMap(func(req *http.Response)(MyDomain, error) {
        //... do something with response
    })
    .onFailure(func(e error) (interface{}, error) {
        // .. optionally do something with first error
    }).get()
```

but is seems it is not that simple :)

1. I cannot pass `func()(*http.Request, error)` where func()(interface{}, error) is expected
2. anyway `Do(func() (string, error) {return "a", nil}..` dont compile either
3. I actually dont care what is supplied to previous call if next caller can handle it - probably some kind of generics would be handy but I didn't find anything in docs about it.
4. I cannot call `.onSuccessMap/.onXXX/..` probably because I return `*Op` rather then `Op` - should I explicitly dereference `*Op`, maybe I shouldn't return `*Op` in first place
5. can I somehow simplify suppliers function so I dont have to pass all those information - it would be nice if compiler figure out what is going on

maybe I think too much in java way and not go way,
any comments/hints will be highly helpful. maybe the whole idea doesn't make sense :]

Comment: `interface{}` does not mean "any type". It means `interface{}`. Go's type system has no covariance. Stop trying to be clever. It doesn't work.

Comment: `on*` and `get` functions are unexported names (first letter is lowercase) so they can't be called from outside that package. My general suggestion would be to stop trying to write JavaScript code in Go.

Comment: @Adrian you know switching languages are always pain, but you dont have to be rude

Comment: @Volker can I use some other type instead of `interface{}` or there is no type that can be used for structs, basic types, string and arrays

Comment: "can I use some other type". No.

Answer (score 1):

This Q&A is very much opinion-based, but my suggestion is **do not** mplement your own error handlers in this fashion.

Since you are you using go 1.13, I would highly recommend you read the new error handling features in the [go-blog](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors).

It allows for chaining errors, and easily unwrapping any particular error type from the error-chain.  With `errors.Is` one can determine if a particular error type occurred. With `errors.As` you can extract the exact details of that error.

`fmt.Errorf` with `%w` is a quick way to generate your own wrapped errors. And if you want more error details, you can simply write your own error types provided they include the `Error` and `Wrap` interfaces.

Comment: thanks for answer,
I ve read the blog post you are sharing but I think those are two different things, one is flow control and another is error handling, my `Op` is just controlling which branch will be executed and that's it - it doesnt act on specific error, such logic should be executed after `.get()`, or am I missing something?